# asymptotic behavior of coefficients in the expansion of $\frac{1}{(1-z)^\alpha}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, gamma-function

From Stein's complex analysis:
prove that if we take
$$
f(z)=\frac{1}{(1-z)^\alpha} \quad\text{for }|z|\lt1
$$
(defined in terms of the principal branch of the logarithm)
where $\alpha$ is a fixed complex number, then
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(\alpha) z^n
$$
with 
$$
a_n(\alpha)\sim\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}n^{\alpha-1}\quad\text{as}\;n\to\infty.
$$

:added

i have calculated
$$
a_n(\alpha)=\frac{\Gamma(n+\alpha)}{n!\Gamma(\alpha)}
$$
so it remains to show:
$$
\frac{\Gamma(n+\alpha)}{\Gamma(n+1)}\sim n^{\alpha-1}\text{for large n}
$$
but i dont see how to prove it

Comment: Use the limit definition of the gamma function

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how one chooses to define the Gamma function this may be a direct result of the definition. One such way to define the Gamma function is as the unique function $\Gamma$ satisfying:

1) $\Gamma(1)=1$.

2) $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$.

3) $\Gamma(z+\alpha)\sim z^\alpha\Gamma(z)$.

which can be shown to be equivalent to the limit definition. Your question follows directly from the last condition above.